# Ed: is possible to substitute between one string and another one?

Tags: ed

This command on ed editor

```
/string.start/;/string.end/dp
```

deleted all words (not the entire line, this happen using `,` instead of `;`) between the `string.start` and `string.end`

Is possible to replace/substitute between `string.start`  and  `string.end`?

I have tried this line

```
s/string.start/;/string.end/mynewline../
```

and this other

```
/string.start/;/string.end/s /mynewline../
```

but both are incorrect.

My goal is to do something like this, with the command

/string.start/;/string.end/dp

The text:

```
This text start with string.start and other words bla bla bla bla then end with string end.
```

Become

```
This text start with
```

I want something like this

```
This text start with string.start and other words bla bla bla bla then end with string end.
```

become

```
This text start with my substituted string.
```

I forgot: the substition must working for different lines, for one line is easy to use 
`s/stringstart.*.string.end/`

Comment: You should add some example documents, together with what you observe is happening when you apply these commands with `ed` and what you want to happen.

Comment: Sure, I will add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `s/string.start/;/string.end/mynewline../` does not appear to be a valid `ed` expression. Neither GNU `ed` nor the native BSD `ed` on my system understands it.  I'm also not able to get `/string.start/;/string.end/dp` working.   The `;` is an address that is the same as `.,$`, i.e. "from this line until the end of the document", and I can't makes sense of it in the middle of the command line that.

The most simple solution would be to use just

```
s/string.start.*string.end/with my substituted string/p
```

This does literally what you want, i.e. substitutes the text between the first match of `string.start` and the last match of `string.end` (including the matching text) on the current line.

This is akin to wanting to substitute the string in the first parenthesis in `some.text(0) -> other.text(2)` by `100`:

```
s/([^)]*)/(100)/
```

That is, you match the start delimiter, followed by whatever text, and then the end delimiter, and replace with the wanted text (in this case, the delimiters should be retained).

To apply the substitution to *all* lines in the document, prepend the command with `%` (or alternatively `1,$`, or just `,`):

```
%s/string.start.*string.end/with my substituted string/p
```

Note that only the last line will be printed.

To print all lines that are affected, use

```
g/string.start.*string.end/ s//with my substituted string/p
```

i.e., apply the substitution to all lines that matches the expression, individually.

Comment: I had already had this idea, it works but only for one line, I want a substitution even on other lines

Comment: @elbarna Could you add an example to the question?

Comment: I have already added

Comment: @elbarna The example in the question is just a single line. Do you want to do a match _across_ lines, or apply this expression to all lines?

Comment: Apply to all lines

Comment: @elbarna See updated answer.